# getting IncompatibleClassChangeError while deploying EAR into WAS8.5 through Jenkins using GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jenkins, websphere

I have Jenkins of 1.611 version, JDK 1.7 and remote WAS8.5 is running on JDK 1.6 version. When I am trying to deploy EAR or WAR file by the help of Github (i.e., I am pushing the project from eclipse Luna which has java 7 configuration), Iam facing the following error:

```
Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
The following artifacts will be deployed in this order...

-------------------------------------------
SpringWSEAR.ear
-------------------------------------------
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.DeploymentServiceException: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:122)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.getAppName(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.createArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:226)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:168)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:764)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:724)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1769)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class]
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.handleException(AppManagementFactory.java:672)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:141)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:91)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentController.readArchive(AppDeploymentController.java:254)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.getAppName(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:108)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:799)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:799)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getWARFileAnnotationsDetector(WARFileImpl.java:2908)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.containsEJBContent(WARFileImpl.java:1975)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1372)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1331)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:512)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:477)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfo(AppInstallHelper.java:563)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementFactory.readArchive(AppManagementFactory.java:129)
    ... 16 more

Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there any version differences between eclipse or jenkins or WAS???
Any Help would be appreciated...

Comment: Try to switch WAS to JDK 1.7, or your Jenkins/Eclipse to JDK 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its got resolved.. I have been using WAS8.5 jars which were running on JDK 1.7. I have replaced those by JDK 1.6 jars. And deployed successfully. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22393) with the WebSphere Deployer Plugin, of which you appear to have filed a duplicate on the Jenkins issue tracker.

The [latest comments](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22393?focusedCommentId=226314) on that issue indicate that a fix has been made, but this has not yet been released.